# Is there way to not include the third argument on the reducer def using mrjob?

Tags: python, mapreduce, mrjob

I was wondering if there was a way to prevent "Top Ten Salaries" from appearing in my output, but I just want just the list. Here is my code:

```
 from mrjob.job import MRJob

class MRWordCount(MRJob):
    
  def mapper(self,_,lines):
    for number in lines.split(','):
      yield None, int(number)
  def reducer(self, _, numbers): 
      yield "Top Ten Salaries", sorted(numbers,reverse = True)[:10]



if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRWordCount.run()
```

Here is my output:

```
"Top Ten Salaries" [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

I do not want to include the text in front of the list. Does anyone know how I would go about this?

Comment: I see no code which print such as text in your example.

Comment: There won't be a print statement in this case. The output is done through the command prompt.

Comment: Pretty strange question. If you don't want to return text - don't do that: `yield sorted(numbers,reverse = True)[:10]`

Comment: Have you used the mrjob package before?

Comment: No, I haven't. You have to return tuple or what?